# Dynamic SUMPRODUCT to Auto Update with New Row

Tags: excel, sum, excel-indirect

I am trying to figure out a way to have a dynamic SUMPRODUCT that automatically update when a new row (expense) is inserted with a different unit price. I'm currently using `=SUM(INDIRECT("D23 :"&ADDRESS(ROW()-2,COLUMN()))` for the sum version to get the total number of units, but I need to do a SUMPRODUCT in order to total different cost per units with the number of units resulting in the total cost for that particular service. The columns are the different services being provided. The SUMPRODUCT isn't working with the INDIRECT and ADDRESS nested to make the arrays. Due to needing more than one total at the bottom for error checking, I cannot use a table. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why are you using `INDIRECT` in the first place??

Comment: Use an Excel Table object, then you can refer to the column like this `TableName[ColumnName]` and new rows will be included. Or use dynamic range names that grow with the data. Indirect is the worst possible approach.

Comment: Teylyn thanks! A.S.H. I'm using INDIRECT for the column totals in order to update automatically when a column is added. Each column is a different product (more or less), I need to give the end user the option to add multiple products. Rows are the expenses for that product. I need the SUMPRODUCT to update when additional expenses (rows) are added. There are multiple sections of expenses on this on spreadsheet. In the past each expense type (salary, equipment, travel, etc.) were on completely separate sheets. I am consolidating to two sheets. One for expense details & the other is the summary.

Comment: I'm going to give the tables a go and scrap the INDIRECT method. Clearly I've been overthinking this. Much appreciated!

Comment: @teylyn The table didn't work. The table only has the ability to have one total at the bottom. I need to have two (one for the total number of units for error checking and one for the total cost, the SUMPRODUCT). And I have to be able to keep the totals in the columns. There are two of those as well because, again, there needs to be one for total number of units for error checking and a total cost for that specific expense. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mix of absolute and relative referencing instead of Indirect. Consider this screenshot:

[image]

The range is referred to with `$F$7:F12` If more row are inserted above the total row, the formula in the total will change to `=SUM($F$7:F13)`, i.e. the range always starts in F7 and will extend to one cell above the current cell.

The formula in F14 calculates the average and uses `=AVERAGE($F$7:F12)`. When another row is inserted above the total row, the formula will change to `=AVERAGE($F$7:F13)`, i.e. start at cell F7 and extend the range to two cells above the current cell.

This concept can be used without issues in all formulas that use ranges.

Comment: Thank you! That simplified my column totals drastically. I need to have a SUMPRODUCT total though too at the bottom and since that uses arrays and not ranges. Is there a simplified method for a dynamic array to use with SUMPRODUCT?

Comment: What do you mean with "arrays, not ranges"? Show the Sumproduct formula.

Comment: '=SUMPRODUCT($E$9:E28,$H$9:H28)'

Comment: Yes, that will also work, of course. But you should see that if you try it in your data. If the Sumproduct formula is below row 28, then rows can be inserted above the formula and it will include the inserted rows.

Comment: I thought so, but for whatever reason it isn't working. The SUMPRODUCT formula does not automatically update when a row is added between the rows 28 and the formula. That's why I was thinking of using a dynamic name range. I think because SUMPRODUCT uses an array instead of a range it doesn't automatically update when rows/columns are updated.

Comment: With all due respect, but that's a load of tosh. Sumproduct takes ranges as arguments. It evaluates the ranges as arrays, but the arguments are ranges of cells. In your formula `=SUMPRODUCT($E$9:E28,$H$9:H28)` you have two ranges. An array would look like `=SUMPRODUCT({1,2,3,4,5,6,7},{5,6,5,6,5,6,5])`.

Comment: Your problem is probably that you insert a row ***after*** the rows that your Sumproduct formula watches. In this case, if you insert a new row after row 28, then of course, the formula will not update, because it is not affected by the row insertion. You have to insert a row between rows 9 and 28, then the Sumproduct will adjust correctly.